# Taking python output to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to take the output from this code into a pandas dataframe. I'm really only trying to pull the first part of the output which is the stock symbols,company name, field3, field4. The output has a lot of other data I'm not interested in but it's giving me everything. Could someone help me to put this into a dataframe if possible?

**The current output is in this format**

```
["ABBV","AbbVie","_DRUGM","S&P 100,&nbsp;S&P 500"],["ABC","AmerisourceBergen","_MEDID","S&P 500"],
```

**Desired Output**

[image: Desired Output]

**Full Code**

```
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    
    url = "https://www.stockrover.com/build/production/Research/tail.js?1644930560"
    
    payload={}
    headers = {}
    
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.  You identify a list of lists as the output but fail to tell us what it is the output of.  You want a dataframe but fail to define what you expect the format of the dataframe to be.  We are good but unfortunately not clairvoyant.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store the data from your tuple of lists, then create a DataFrame based on that dictionary. In my solution below, I omit the 'ID' field because the index of the DataFrame serves the same purpose.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Store the data you're getting from requests
data = ["ABBV","AbbVie","_DRUGM","S&P 100,&nbsp;S&P 500"],["ABC","AmerisourceBergen","_MEDID","S&P 500"]

# Create an empty dictionary with relevant keys
dic = {
    "Ticker": [],
    "Name": [],
    "Field3": [],
    "Field4": []
}

# Append data to the dictionary for every list in your `response`
for pos, lst in enumerate(data):
    dic['Ticker'].append(lst[0])
    dic['Name'].append(lst[1])
    dic['Field3'].append(lst[2])
    dic['Field4'].append(lst[3])

# Create a DataFrame from the dictionary above
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

The resulting dictionary looks like so.

[image: Resulting DataFrame from code above.]

### Edit: A More Efficient Approach

In my solution above, I manually called the `list` form of each key in the `dic` dictionary. Using `zip` we can streamline the process and have it work for any length response and any changes you make to the labels of the dictionary.

The only caveat to this method is that you have to make sure the order of keys in the dictionary lines up with the data in each list in your response. For example, if `Ticker` is the first dictionary key, the ticker must be the first item in the list resulted from your `response`. This was true for the first solution, too, however.

```py
new_dic = {
    "Ticker": [],
    "Name": [],
    "Field3": [],
    "Field4": []
}

for pos, lst in enumerate(data): # Iterate position and list
    for key, item in zip(new_dic, data[pos]): # Iterate key and item in list
        new_dic[key].append(item) # Append to each key the item in list

df = pd.DataFrame(new_dic)
```

The result is identical to the method above:

[image: Identical result using more efficient code.]

### Edit (even better!)

I'm coming back to this after learning from a commenter that `pd.DataFrame()` can input two-dimensional array data and output a `DataFrame`. This would streamline the *entire* process several times over:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Store the data you're getting from requests
data = ["ABBV","AbbVie","_DRUGM","S&P 100,&nbsp;S&P 500"],["ABC","AmerisourceBergen","_MEDID","S&P 500"]

# Define columns
columns = ['ticker', 'name', 'field3', 'field4']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
```

The result (same as first two):

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your solutions very much, they work really nice!  Can you point me in the right direction how to pull the information directly from the output instead of having the data hardcoded like data = ["ABBV".  Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: I'm not sure why you build a new dictionary and then append to it? If you have to rely on the position in the list, then just do this one line and it does exactly the same (data as a list like in OP's post): `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['ticker', 'name', 'field3', 'field4'])`

Comment: @JR Sure thing. Saving your outputs to variables is generally good practice. But, something you can do is convert your `requests.response()` output to JSON formatting using the `.json()` function: `response = requests.get(url).json()` for example. This will make `type(response)` a dictionary. You can subvert the `dic`/`new_dic` dictionaries in this way as long as you modify the code to interpret the `response` in the way it is returned.

Comment: @Rabinzel Wow! I tried that and it worked perfectly. I didn't know you can pass `pd.DataFrame()` a tuple of lists (two-dimensional list data I guess?) and have a `DataFrame` output. Just edited my answer to reflect your idea. Learned something totally new today, thank you!

Comment: I played around with it a bit in the past because I couldn't figure out if `pd.DataFrame` takes my input data row- or columnwise. By the time you have different data with different format goals. If you pass a dict, your key is the column name and the value (which is e.g a list then) are the column values. If you just pass a list of lists (or tuples) to the dataframe, every list/tuple represents a row and the dataframe's columns are the length of every list. [see documentation of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) there are good examples. You're welcome!

Comment: the good thing is, I didn't know about the json thingy with request. Will try it myself. So we helped each other :) .....and I hope we helped the OP too!